# Set flags based on record created date

Tags: formula

Before 2 years lead records are created for that i want to set green color flag using formula field
for after 2 years lead records are created for that i want to set red color flag using formula field. I tried like this but i am not getting result.

```
IF( created date > TODAT(), IMAGE("/img/samples/color_red.gif"),
IF( created date < TODAT(),IMAGE("/img/samples/color_yellow.gif")))
```

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula will look like this and replace with proper images

```
IF(FLOOR( (NOW()- CreatedDate))> 730,
    "greater than 2 years", 
    "less than 2 years"
)
```

Comment: It's working fine.Thanks for your help bro and quick response.

Comment: If my answer solves your purpose then accept this, do that others may find this useful

Comment: Bro here we need some changes in my formula Before 5 years(2013) lead records are created for that i want to set yellow color flag,
& In between 2 years(2013-2016) to 5 years lead records are created for that i want to set green color flag,
& In between 1 years(2017) to 2nd year lead records are created for that i want to set blue color flag,
& In between 6 months (22-10-2018) to 1 year lead records are created for that i want to set red color flag.

Comment: I tried this but it is showing errors,Can you please help me -IF(FLOOR((TODAY()-  Sales_Order_Date__c ))> 184 && 
FLOOR(( TODAY()-  Sales_Order_Date__c )) >360 && 
FLOOR(( TODAY()-  Sales_Order_Date__c )) >1825,
IMAGE("/resource/green", "green",30,30)|| 
IMAGE("/resource/red1", "red1",30,30)||
IMAGE("/resource/blue", "blue",30,30))

Comment: You can post a new question with those comments

Answer (score 0):

once try this formula

IMAGE( 
 IF(( Source_Order_Date__c  -  TODAY() )<= (-540),
"/img/samples/flag_green.gif", 
IF(( Source_Order_Date__c  -  TODAY() )>= (-180),
"/img/samples/flag_yellow.gif",
IF(( Source_Order_Date__c  -  TODAY() )>= 0,
"/img/samples/flag_red.gif",
 "/s.gif"
)
)
),
  "Invalid."
)